# What is my BufferedImage constructor doing -- 'new BufferedImage[2]'?

Tags: java

I have the following line of Java, but when I look at the documentation (which I'll link), I don't understand what my (inherited) code is doing.  My line of code provides one argument  whereas the documentation lays out three different constructor methods, none of which handle just one argument.  **The primary thing I want to understand is: which of the constructor methods is being used in by my code, and why?** I read up on constructors and overloading, I read up on the Image superclass, but no clues popped out to me. Please be nice; I'm still new to Java.

`BufferedImage[] bufferedImages = new BufferedImage[2];`

From the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

```
BufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable<?,?> properties)
Constructs a new BufferedImage with a specified ColorModel and Raster.

BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
Constructs a BufferedImage of one of the predefined image types.

BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType, IndexColorModel cm)
Constructs a BufferedImage of one of the predefined image types: TYPE_BYTE_BINARY or TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED.
```

Comment: Your code is only creating an array of size 2. It doesn't create any instances of BufferedImage.

Comment: Each array element is set to null.

Comment: Notice the square brackets [ ] on the right .  They indicate that this is not a constructor call. This code creates an array of size 2. Each entry could contain a BufferedImage, but non have been created yet.  You can imagine the array as looking like this [ null ] [ null ]

Comment: Gonen, thank you for the helpful comment!  Would you make that an answer ?  I found it to be so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That line of code is not a constructor for a `BufferedImage`. Rather, it is a constructor for an array of `BufferedImage` of size 2.